# Layout actionlink routing incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've found a way around this, with some issues but, I don't understand why it's happening, there's also probably a better way around this issue than I've come up with.

In my *_Layout* which is in the *Shared* folder, I've got `@Html.ActionLink("Firewall", "Create", "Firewalls", new {  @class = "button roundedCorners" })` which is rendering in the html as `<a class="button roundedCorners" href="/Home/Create?Length=9">Firewall</a>`.

If I add `,null` to the end, the link works, but the class styling is ignored.

The below also works, but again ignores the styling `@Html.RouteLink("Firewall", "Default", new {  @class = "button roundedCorners", controller = "Firewalls", action = "Create"})`.

That is the wrong controller, why would it be setting the route as `Home` when I'm explicitly passing `Firewalls`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Firewall", "Create", "Firewalls", null, new {  @class = "button roundedCorners" })
```

The 4th parameter is the route values and the 5th parameter is the html attributes

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Would explain why removing the css class allowed proper functionality.

Comment: He hasn't removed the class, he has set the `RouteValues` parameter to null as you're not passing in any route values.  You were passing in the wrong values into the wrong parameters - the html attributes into the route values parameter.

Comment: That's not what I meant - in my example I had the class as the fourth parameter, when removing it and only leaving it as Name, Action, Controller, the desired route was used.

Comment: That's because having three parameters is a valid overload for Html.ActionLink.  When you pass in alien values into the fourth parameter for that overload, it won't know how to interpret and generate a link to the desired route.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple overloads of Html.ActionLink.  In your example you're trying to pass in `HtmlAttributes` values into the `RouteValues` parameter.

Here are some valid overloads for your particular case:

```
// Link Text and Action
@Html.ActionLink("Firewall", "Create")

// Link Text, Action and Controller name
@Html.ActionLink("Firewall", "Create", "Firewalls")

// Link Text, Action, Controller name, Route Values and Html Attributes
@Html.ActionLink("Firewall", "Create", "Firewalls", new { forUser = "PurpleSmurph" }, new { @class = "button roundedCorners" })
```

In the last example I passed in a route value that doesn't exist within your application so the route engine will add the additional *route values* as a query string of the generated URL:

```
<a class="button roundedCorners" href="/Home/Create?forUser=PurpleSmurph">Firewall</a>
```

But as you don't want any additional query string values, in Stephen Muecke's example, it is set to `null`, to produce:

```
<a class="button roundedCorners" href="/Home/Create">Firewall</a>
```

I hope this helps!  You can see the different overloads on the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!